# notify-send fails to specify a destination, and my notification doesn't appear onscreen. Why?

Tags: notifications, icewm

Notification through libnotify seems to work under icewm, as the different notifications from applications like konversation show. But I can't get it to work from the command line using the notify-send command. When I try it, the notification doesn't appear on my screen at all.

How can I get it to work under icewm?

**Edit 1:** I've now tried dbus-monitor. It seems there's a problem with notify-send: it isn't specifying any destination, whereas konversation for example specifies knotify as destination. Maybe this is what's causing the problem?

**Edit 2:** I've also tried d-feet to reproduce the query :(see http://dropcanvas.com/521xc/97), still nothing.

The query I tried to reproduce was this one:

```
method call sender=:1.14 -> dest=org.kde.knotify serial=1024 path=/Notify; interface=org.kde.KNotify; member=event  
   string "queryMessage"  
   string "konversation"  
   array [  
   ]  
   string ""  
   string "<html>&lt;ychaouche|ghost&gt; hello</html>"  
   array [  
   ]  
   array [  
   ]  
   int32 -1  
   int64 33554870  
method return sender=:1.8 -> dest=:1.14 reply_serial=1024  
   int32 1072
```

It was captured using dbus-monitor, sent from konversation when receiving a PM from myself to myself (using xchat, konversation and two nicks).

Comment: What was your command line? And what does “not work” mean? Did you get an error message, a kernel panic, did the notification not appear? What about the return value of `notify-send`?

Comment: A got the BSOD... more seriously, not work means nothing happened.

Comment: the command line was notify-send "halp" "hahaha"

Comment: This works for me. Can you start `dbus-monitor` and run the command again? Check if you can see the notification request.

Comment: Oh thanks for the dbus-monitor tip, appearantly there's a problem with notify-send : it's putting no destination somewhere, whereas konversation for example puts knotify as destination. Maybe the problem comes from here ? http://pastie.org/5190564

Answer (score 1):

This should work from the command line.

```
notify-send -u normal -t 60 -a cli "test notification" "This is simply a notification"
```

I built this string reading directly from the `notify-send --help` information.

Of course, the man page gives more detailed information.

Comment: It Didn't. (stupid character limitation text).

Comment: @ychaouche The "stupid character limitation text" is because it's helpful if you include details like what went wrong

Comment: So what exactly did it do?

Comment: Nothing. Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo

Comment: It can't really do nothing, it either terminated successfully or it terminated with an error, or it is still running.

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe try the solution via `dbus-send` [proposed there](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8437808&postcount=3) :

```
dbus-send --session --type=method_call --reply-timeout=10000 \
  --dest=org.freedesktop.Notifications \
  /org/freedesktop/Notifications  org.freedesktop.Notifications.Notify \
  string:"app_name" \
  uint32:0 \
  string:'app_icon' \
  string:"summary" \
  string:"body" \
  array:string:"" \
  dict:string:string:"",""\
  int32:10000
```

`notify-send` is actually a wrapper around this command.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. However, using dbus-monitor, I could capture this message : http://pastie.org/5190800. Do you know how to translate this into that ?

Comment: This works for me as well as the `notify-send` command you proposed. I believe your problem is not in the request.

Comment: from [this page](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Dbus,_naughty_and_logs) they propose to set the environment variable `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` before running notify-send. Maybe you could try their solution.

Comment: Thanks vincent, but still nothing http://pastie.org/5194703 :(